# How should laravel queues set up properly for production with supervisor?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I'm trying to setup the use of queues for log storaging, e-mail sending and other tasks.

I decided to use **beanstalkd** and supervisor to control the jobs queue execution. I installed `pda/pheanstalk ~2.0` with composer, did the proper setups at `app/config/queue.php`, wrote my Queue class and attempted to execute a task.

This is an example, it's a log in log:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
                        'email' => $email,
                        'password' => $password
                        ));

if (Auth::check()) {
$debounce = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10);
Queue::later($debounce, 'SaveAcessLog', array('user' =>  Auth::id(), 'ip' => Request::getClientIp()));
}
```

So for supervisord I followed [this tutorial](http://posts.danharper.me/laravel-queue-supervisor/). After installing it, I followed each step and made sure to make the `laravel_queue.conf` also the `run_queue.sh` files executable.

The problem is that I can't get any task executed. When I test `sudo supervisorctl` I obtain:

```
laravel_queue                    FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Accessing the supervisord log file at `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` shows:

```
2015-04-02 20:16:57,251 INFO supervisord started with pid 1269
2015-04-02 20:16:58,254 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 1316
2015-04-02 20:16:58,277 INFO exited: laravel_queue (exit status 127; not expected)
2015-04-02 20:16:59,279 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 1525
2015-04-02 20:16:59,287 INFO exited: laravel_queue (exit status 127; not expected)
2015-04-02 20:17:01,294 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 1753
2015-04-02 20:17:01,303 INFO exited: laravel_queue (exit status 127; not expected)
2015-04-02 20:17:04,658 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 1808
2015-04-02 20:17:04,668 INFO exited: laravel_queue (exit status 127; not expected)
2015-04-02 20:17:05,669 INFO gave up: laravel_queue entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

So, if I try `php artisan queue:work` the task will get executed! What am I missing with my supervisord setup?

#### Note

I'm open to use something different to supervisord in case it's simpler or more efficient.

Comment: I honestly couldn't achieve it then, I will try again and let you know if succeed, same, tell me if you get it, please!

Answer (score 3):

Check if supervisor `startsecs=0` helps. [Supervisor docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values)

My config:

```
[program:myqueue]
#command=php artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=10 --verbose
command=php artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=90 --tries=1 -vvv
## --timeout=0 --tries=0
#user=user
directory=/usr/share/nginx/laravel
stdout_logfile=/usr/share/nginx/laravel/app/storage/logs/myqueue_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
startsecs=0
#autorestart=false
#startretries=0
#exitcodes=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I've had more luck using `artisan queue:listen` in my supervisor config, that way it doesn't keep starting and stopping the process but should restart if it does stop for some reason.

**Update**

It seems like this isn't the best solution, I've found that it will run the queue most of the time. However if there's a long period with no jobs to process, new jobs don't seem to get processed unless supervisor is told to start the worker again.

**More update**

I now have a configuration similar to the the following:

```
[program:worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
startretries=10
stdout_logfile=/dir/logs/worker.log
```

It seems to work well and hasn't fallen over for a long time.

Comment: as far as i know theres a advantage of using  *queue:work --daemon over  queue:listen* since  daemon process are efficient at utilizing CPU :)